# Italian universities: how to find out the "hiring plans" for researchers in the next 1-4 years?

Tags: mathematics, career-path, job-search, early-career, italy

In Italian universities (mathematics departments), is there a way to find out in advance what are the "hiring plans" for the next 1-4 years? In fact, when is it known within a university administration that RTDa/b positions will be available in a department? Is it a matter of just a few months in advance or is there planning/scheduling of years in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are typically no such long-term plans. A few months is more common.

You might find these plans in the proceedings of the academic senates, which are public, but I wouldn't find that particularly useful.

Comment: This is probably accurate for most countries. A year ahead is about the maximum reasonable horizon for most purposes. Exceptions would be when there is a long range plan to remove a department or to expand one. But expansion "plans" would likely be subject to annual revision. Things change and there are a lot of variables.

Comment: I'd also guess that math departments tend to be pretty stable over time, reacting, slowly, to general economic trends. If a department has a lot of older faculty you might naturally expect that it will need to hire replacements as they retire. Not just Italy, but especially places with mandatory retirement age.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have a follow-up question: where does the funding for new RTDa/b positions come from in Italy? And how long before the publication of a call is the university aware of the existence of such funding/available positions?